# How to deal with different proportions of positive samples in train vs. test data for logistic regression?

Tags: logistic, panel-data, unbalanced-classes

I want to train a logistic regression model with random effects. In training data there is only 0.5% of positive individuals, whereas in test set there is around 5% of positives. I want to train a random effect model, so I can not just drop some observations because this is a longitudinal study. Is there any possibility to adjust fitted model or so, such that it would be independent of proportions of positives and negatives in training set?

Comment: Watch out for how you do your train/test split when you have a time component.

Comment: I know there will be more positives in future time, so even when I divide them now in a "better" way it will not solve the problem for future predictions. Or did I misunderstood what you meant?

Comment: It's more of a general comment about doing out-of-sample testing when there is a time component.